# wrong results of st_distance when using srid 32636

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have 2 tables with `srid = 32636`
According to: https://epsg.io/32636 the units of this `srid` is `metes`.

When I run the following query:

```
select st_distance(a.geo, b.geo)
from table_a as a, table_b as b
```

I'm getting huge distances (thousands of km)

When I run this query:

```
select ST_Distance_Sphere(st_transform(a.geo, 4326), st_transform(b.geo, 4326))
from table_a as a, table_b as b
```

I'm getting results with more sense (10-500 meters)

What am I missing ?

- The `st_distance` of two same `srids` which are in meters, doesn't give results in meters ?
- Why do I need to transform it to other `srid` and use `ST_Distance_Sphere` for correct results ?
- How can I measure the distance in meters without transform it to other `srid` ?

Comment: Can you post the coordinates of a couple of points you want to check, and can you post the results you get, and expect to get?

Comment: SRID 4326 measures in longitude and latitude, do distance doesn't make much sense there.

Comment: UTM introduces huge distortion outside of each zone bounds. Make sure you have used the proper zone